# animating button Allowuserinteraction not working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I have a UIbutton created in code in an NSObject class which controls a game in a UIViewController class. The button works fine throughout most of the game, but at a certain point I want the button to fadein/out. Once the fadein/out starts animating the button is no longer interactive. I have set the .AllowUserInteraction option, but still no luck. I am stumped on this one, so any help much appreciated!

```
Class GameController: NSObject {
var gameView: UIView!
var nextButton: UIButton!

func gameViewSetUp() {
    // create the nextButton
    let imageNextButton = UIImage(named: "rightArrow") as UIImage?
    self.nextButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(ScreenWidth-100,ScreenHeight-250,60,60)
    nextButton.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    nextButton.setImage(imageNextButton, forState: .Normal)
    nextButton.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    nextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    nextButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    nextButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
    nextButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    nextButton.addTarget(self, action: "nextPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    nextButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    gameView.addSubview(nextButton)

func playStageX() { 
       nextButtonWink()
    }
}

func nextButtonWink() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0, options: [.AllowUserInteraction, .Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut, .Autoreverse],
        animations: {
 // self.nextButton.userInteractionEnabled = true // I tried this as well but no impact.
            self.nextButton.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
private var controller: GameController
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    controller = GameController()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    let gameView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))
    self.view.addSubview(gameView)
    controller.gameView = gameView
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take out  `self.nextButton.alpha = 0` to test this out,  I believe that button events will not fire when alpha is zero.  When it comes to animations,  the actual object's alpha will get set to zero before the animation starts,  and what you are seeing is like a rendered interactive screenshot of your view as it animates

If that is the case,  then you need to set the alpha to something like 0.0100000003 or override the button to be interactive at alpha 0

Comment: @Knight0fDragon very good answer, but setting alpha to 0.0..1 does not make the button interactive again. Do you have any more suggestion? I don't know how to override the UIBUtton

Comment: @theAlse, the minimum allowable alpha i found is 0.0100000003

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so setting alpha to 0.01 will make the button interactive again?

Comment: @theAlse,no, that is less than the number I gave you

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't get the magical number 0.0100000003, but will give it a try

Comment: @theAlse I wrote a demo app and I found anything smaller than that number would not work

Comment: if you find that there is still slight blending issues with the low alpha, you can use a UIImageView to dispaly the graphic of the button, and have the button itself have a background color of `.clear`, with the button alpha set to 1

Comment: Anthing strictly greater than 0.1 will make the button interactive again. @Knight0fDragon seems to have found 0.0100000003 to be the lowest such CGFloat.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 Xcode 8:

AllowUserAction is now deprecated to allowUserAction.... go figure

```
func nextButtonWink() {
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction,
    animations: {
```