# How to make a button flash or blink?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to change a button's color (just a flash/blink) to green when a scan is correct and red when there's a problem. I am able to do this with a view like so

```
func flashBG(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    })
}
```

But with a button it stays green

```
func flashBtn(){
    UIButton.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.buttonScan.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    })
}
```

I have created the button by code

```
func setupScanButton() {
    let X_Co = (self.view.frame.size.width - 100)/2
    let Y_Co = (self.viewForLayer.frame.size.height + 36/2)

    buttonScan.frame = CGRectMake(X_Co,Y_Co,100,100)
    buttonScan.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    buttonScan.layer.borderWidth = 2
    buttonScan.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    buttonScan.setTitle("Scan", forState: .Normal)
    buttonScan.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    buttonScan.addTarget(self, action: "buttonScanAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    buttonScan.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:255/255, green: 255/255, blue:255/255, alpha: 1), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.view.addSubview(buttonScan)
}
```

Should i call setupScanButton() again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope that will solve your problem.

```
buttonScan.alpha = 1.0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {

    buttonScan.alpha = 0.0

}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @DaniSpringer which swift version you are using?

Comment: 4.2 I’m pretty sure

Comment: Is button response touches when it is animating ?

Answer (score 35):

This should work in Swift 4

```
extension UIView{
     func blink() {
         self.alpha = 0.2
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {self.alpha = 1.0}, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

Comment: this answer works great! this is how I used it directly on a button (no extension necessary): **myButton.alpha = 0.2
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {myButton.alpha = 1.0}, completion: nil)**

Comment: @LanceSamaria I'm happy that I helped you :)

Answer (score 22):

This will start and stop a flashing button `onClick`, if you only want to flash the button immediately just use the first statement.

```
var flashing = false

@IBAction func btnFlash_Clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !flashing{
            self.buttonScan.alpha = 1.0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
                self.buttonScan.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            })
            
            flashing = true
        }
    else{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .BeginFromCurrentState], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.buttonScan.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })
    }
}
```

### Swift 5.x version

An updated version with `extension`.

```
extension UIView {
    func blink(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, alpha: CGFloat = 0.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            self.alpha = alpha
        })
    }
}
```

To call the function:

```
button.blink() // without parameters
button.blink(duration: 1, delay: 0.1, alpha: 0.2) // with parameters
```

To stop animation: credit to [link](https://mobiraft.com/ios/swift/swift-recipe/how-to-add-blink-or-flash-effect-on-uiview/)

```
func stopBlinking() {
    self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get user interaction to work with the alpha at 0.0.  [See this answer for details.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34297078/1203475)

Comment: @Rashwan L, how can this be modified to flash, lets say 5 times only?

Comment: @theAlse, declare a variable like: `var counter = 0` and then inside of func btnFlash_Clicked make a if statement like `if counter > 4 { return }` and at the bottom of `btnFlash_Clicked` just increase the counters value with 1.

Comment: @RashwanL thanks for the reply, I had already tried that without success, there is something fishy going on that I don't undrestand, counter is only increased once and the flashing never ends.

Comment: @theAlse, [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2TR9xoKqvZNRWtZUlhjUDJiOWc) is an example project that I created for you where the button blinks five times. Download the project and you´ll see how this can be done.

Answer (score 11):

### **Swift 4**:

I've maked an extension with some useful options:

```
extension UIButton {
    open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return self.bounds.contains(point) ? self : nil
    }
    func blink(enabled: Bool = true, duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, stopAfter: CFTimeInterval = 0.0 ) {
        enabled ? (UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, //Time duration you want,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 0.0 },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 1.0 })) : self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        if !stopAfter.isEqual(to: 0.0) && enabled {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + stopAfter) { [weak self] in
                self?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, I've overrided the `hittest` function to **enabling** the **touch** also when the button have the `alpha` equals to **0.0** (**transparent**) during the animation.

Then , **all input vars have a default value** so you can launch the `blink()` method without parameters

I've introduced also the `enabled` parameter to start or stop the animations on your button.

Finally, if you want **you can stop animation after a specific time** with the `stopAfter` parameter.

### **Usage:**

```
yourButton.blink() // infinite blink effect with the default duration of 1 second

yourButton.blink(enabled:false) // stop the animation

yourButton.blink(duration: 2.0) // slowly the animation to 2 seconds

yourButton.blink(stopAfter:5.0) // the animation stops after 5 seconds.
```

**Typical uses:**

```
yourButton.blink(duration: 1.5, stopAfter:10.0)
// your code..
yourButton.blink()
// other code..
yourButton.blink(enabled:false)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func blink() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, //Time duration you want,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .Autoreverse, .Repeat],
            animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 0.0 },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 1.0 })
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            [weak self] in
            self?.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just removed the view.

Comment: In swift 3+, I do:  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { 
   loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
  }

Answer (score 4):

```
//MARK : Usage 

yourButton.flash()

extension UIButton {

    func flash() {

        let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        flash.duration = 0.5
        flash.fromValue = 1
        flash.toValue = 0.1
        flash.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        flash.autoreverses = true
        flash.repeatCount = 3

        layer.add(flash, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func btnFlash_Clicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !flashing{
        callButton.alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            callButton.alpha = 0.5
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })

        flashing = true
    }
    else{
        flashing = false
        callButton.alpha = 0.5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            callButton.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with ***UIViewPropertyAnimator*** and **Swift 5**

```
UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear,.repeat], animations: {
       UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3000)
       self.buttonScan.alpha = 0.0
 }, completion: {_ in   })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.alpha = 0.7

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                      delay: 1.0,
                    options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear, UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat, UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse],
                 animations: { myButton.alpha = 1.0 },
                 completion: nil)
```

Comment: @JobinsJohn try myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, but i am not able to doit properly. My basic idea is to run the application for maybe 2 or 3 seconds and then stop it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func animateFlash() {        
    flashView.alpha = 0
    flashView.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { flashView.alpha = 1.0 }) { finished in flashView.isHidden = true }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `UIView` extension "blinks" a view and changes the background colour:

```
/**
 Blinks a view with a given duration and optional color.

 - Parameter duration: The duration of the blink.
 - Parameter color: The color of the blink.
 */
public func blink(withDuration duration: Double = 0.25, color: UIColor? = nil) {

    alpha = 0.2
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.alpha = 1.0
    })

    guard let newBackgroundColor = color else { return }
    let oldBackgroundColor = backgroundColor

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.backgroundColor = newBackgroundColor
        self.backgroundColor = oldBackgroundColor
    })

}
```

You would then use as follows:

```
buttonScan.blink(color: .green)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another smoothly animating version for Swift 5:**

```
 public extension UIView {
  func blink(duration: TimeInterval) {
    let initialAlpha: CGFloat = 1
    let finalAlpha: CGFloat = 0.2
    
    alpha = initialAlpha
    
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState) {
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
        self.alpha = finalAlpha
      }
      
      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
        self.alpha = initialAlpha
      }
    }
  }
}
```