# Make label text "blink" or "flash" on separate button press in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, button, text, blink

Given an app with an on-screen text label and a button. Every time the button is pressed, the text changes. I want to be able to press the button and the text will "blink" when changing text, to make the text change more apparent to the user.

Given the following variables:

```
@IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!
@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {}
```

I've tried SKAction, fadein/fadeout but all tutorials/help are in older versions of Swift and aren't working for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666136/swift-how-to-make-a-button-flash-or-blink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to make a button flash or blink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666136/swift-how-to-make-a-button-flash-or-blink)

Comment: Are you tried to change an alpha value of UILabel ? It's just works

Comment: There's a lot of fun ways you can accomplish this with UIKit, I don't have the time right now to write out the code for you, but do some research into UIView's animation methods like `animateWithDuration` or `transitionWith` and `transitionFrom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**
    One of the method to blink of `UIView` is achieved by `UIKit` animations.

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

var x = 0
let text = ["Vanakkam","Hello","Hi","Hola","Ni Hao","Oi","Namastae"]

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
        self.label.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (bool) in
            self.label.alpha = 1.0
            self.label.text = text[self.x]
            if self.x < text.count{
                self.x = self.x+1
            }else{
                self.x = 0
            }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:-**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As I posted already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493987/1836369

You can extend the class UIView like this:

```
 extension UIView{
     func blink() {
         self.alpha = 0.2
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {self.alpha = 1.0}, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

In this way you can simply call

```
text.blink()
```

to make your label blink