# UIView block based animation weird behavior

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, block, frame

I have got this very simple animation (case):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var v: UIView!
var b = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 120, y: 250, width: 30, height: 30))
    self.v.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(self.v)
}

@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveLinear],
                   animations: {
                    if self.b {
                        self.v.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 250, width: 30, height: 30)
                    } else {
                        self.v.frame = CGRect(x: 240, y: 250, width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                    self.b = !self.b
    },
                   completion: nil)
}
}
```

On each tap of the button the red view moves to left or right depending on current direction. The animation should start from the current position and to be linear.

However if I tap the button when the previous animation is already in progress then the red view **does not start immediately** to move in the opposite direction. It just freezes in the current position while the previous animation finishes and then starts moving. If I change the animation curve option from `linear` to `easeOut` and it works properly.

I am using iOS 10, Xcode 8.2.1

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

I tis because of the additive animations in iOS 8 and above. Here is a very useful link which explains what actually happens and why the animation freezes.

http://iosoteric.com/additive-animations-animatewithduration-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 0):

When the animation is on, the UI components will not react to new changes. It will buffer the input and react once the animation is complete. 
This is not related to the iOS or Xcode versions, but a normal behaviour.

Comment: This is not true because if I change `alpha` instead it works fine. Also if I change the animation option from `linear` to `easeOut` it also works as expected.

Comment: Can you specify the `alpha` values when it works and when it doesn't. Also have a look at the answer from [Knight0fDragon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296002/animating-button-allowuserinteraction-not-working)

Comment: If I animate the alpha value instead of the frame then it works as expected